# Automapper - IncludeBase abstract generic parent cause "...is not derived from" error

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 3 entities: `QuestionA`, `QuestionB`, `QuestionC` which all derives from abstract `BaseQuestion`.

Then I have `AnswerA` which derives `BaseAnswer<QuestionA>`, `AnswerB` which derives `BaseAnswer<QuestionB>`, `AnswerC` which derives `BaseAnswer<QuestionC>`,

I need to map `AnswerA` to `AnswerDTO` (same as B and C).

So I wrote this code:

```
CreateMap<BaseAnswer<BaseQuestion>, AnswerDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.UserDisplay,
        o => o.MapFrom(x => $"{x.User.FirstName} {x.User.LastName}"));

CreateMap<AnswerB, AnswerDTO>()
    .IncludeBase<BaseAnswer<BaseQuestion>, AnswerDTO>();
```

But it cause this error:

```
AnswerB is not derived from BaseAnswer`1[BaseQuestion]. (Parameter 'derivedType')
```

I tried to change it like that

```
CreateMap<AnswerB, AnswerDTO>()
    .IncludeBase<BaseAnswer<QuestionB>, AnswerDTO>();
```

and add:

```
CreateMap<BaseAnswer<QuestionB>, AnswerDTO>()
    .IncludeBase<BaseAnswer<BaseQuestion>, AnswerDTO>();
```

But i cause similar error.

I could write it like this and it works, but its redundant:

```
CreateMap<BaseAnswer<QuestionA>, AnswerDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.UserDisplay,
        o => o.MapFrom(x => $"{x.User.FirstName} {x.User.LastName}"));

CreateMap<BaseAnswer<QuestionB>, AnswerDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.UserDisplay,
        o => o.MapFrom(x => $"{x.User.FirstName} {x.User.LastName}"));

CreateMap<BaseAnswer<QuestionC>, AnswerDTO>()
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.UserDisplay,
        o => o.MapFrom(x => $"{x.User.FirstName} {x.User.LastName}"));
```

Comment: There's no inheritence relationship between BaseAnswer<BaseQuestion> and BaseAnswer<DerivedQuestion>. True the generic arguments themselves have a relationship, but the overall types do not

Comment: Try including the open generic map instead.